# async method signature for events

Tags: c#, async-await

I am working on a xamarin/C# project. I have an event method like this:

```
        void Handle_SearchButtonPressed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Let's suppose i want to call an async method with await like this:

```
        void Handle_SearchButtonPressed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
             await my_async_method();
        }
```

I need to add aync keyword like this:

```
        async void Handle_SearchButtonPressed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
             await my_async_method();
        }
```

It works fine. But, in theory, i should also replace void type by Task. If i do this, i get an error (wrong method signature).

So my question is: Why does it works with void ? In theory it should not work.

Second question: How does it works (internal) to call Handle_SearchButtonPressed without await.

Thanks

Comment: *"But, in theory, i should also replace void type by Task"* - nope if it's an event handler.

Comment: @maccettura: Minor side point: those aren't official Microsoft docs.

Comment: @StephenCleary _and how would you know?_

Comment: @StephenCleary but seriously, I missed that.  Saw MSDN and just quickly posted.

Comment: To add to @Sinatr's comment, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) is a very informative blog post **by the expert in async/await**.

Comment: How should i do if a need to call an async method inside a constructor ? I cannot put async on constructor ?